# Столбец из таблицы html в столбец mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, база-данных

Есть проблема, как новичок не знаю как решить. Есть HTML таблица

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><select name="signature" class="browser-default">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><select name="signature" class="browser-default">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><select name="signature" class="browser-default">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
```

Нужно каждый столбец таблицы занести в столбец mySQL БД. Как это сделать?
p.s. заранее спасибо

Comment: Как данные с mysql будут выводиться?

Comment: через SELECT из столбцов val1, val2, val3, val5, val5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Запихиваете Вашу таблицу в форму с методом POST и экшеном, ведущим на файл php-обработчика, задаёте инпутам разные имена и добавляете сабмит для отправки данных:

```html
<form method="post" action="file.php">
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="name1" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name2" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name3" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name4" /></td>
     <td><select name="signature" class="browser-default">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

2. В PHPMyAdmin создаёте (если ещё не создана) базу данных и таблицу этой базы, куда будут заноситься данные из HTML-таблицы.
3. В файле file.php пишете примерно следующее:

```html
<?php

//соединение с базой данных
$link = mysqli_connect('ваш хост', 'логин', 'пароль');

//выбор базы данных
mysqli_select_db($link, 'имя базы');

//получение данных из HTML-таблицы
$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$name3 = $_POST['name3'];
$name4 = $_POST['name4'];
$signature = $_POST['signature'];

//занесение данных в базу
$query = "INSERT INTO имяТаблицы (поле1, поле2, поле3, поле4, полеSignature) VALUES ('$name1', '$name2', '$name3', '$name4', '$signature')";

mysqli_query($link, $query);

?>
```

4. Чтобы всё это работало, Вам, разумеется, нужен какой-то локальный сервер - например OpenServer. Файлы складываете в папку C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost

Answer (score 0):

Что бы работать с mysql вам понадобиться php или другой серверный язык программирования. В данном случае можно таблицу засунуть в форму, которая будет отправляться на сервер, где уже будет осуществляться запрос к БД (для вставки insert). Еще есть вариант доставать данный из инпутов аяксом, для этого понадобиться javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить что запрос действительно будет по типу:

```
SELECT val1, val2, val3, val5, val5 FROM `table`
```

Тогда таблицу можно вывести вот так:

```
    $result = []; //Результат SQL запроса
    <?php foreach ($result as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="<?php echo $item['val1']; ?>"> value="<?php echo $item['val1']; ?>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="<?php echo $item['val2']; ?>"> value="<?php echo $item['val2']; ?>" />
            </td>
            ...
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="<?php echo $item['val5']; ?>"> value="<?php echo $item['val5']; ?>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

А вообще лучше уточнять как Вы работаете с базой и как выводите собираете с базы, так сложно сказать.